# EF CodeFirst DateTime in nested object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

In our EF-models we have a lot of To/From (DateTime) members. I was trying a new concept yesterday where I put these To/from in a new class (DateTimePeriod) to make life easier.

Example

```
public partial class SomeEfModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimePeriod Time { get; set; }
}
public class DateTimePeriod
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

This works like expected, but I realized that Time sometimes will be null. Since EF creates From/To as non-nullable in the database, then Time cannot be null.

Can I somehow still have From/To as non-nullable in code, but having them nullable in the database? And if they are null, the Time-property should be null when fetched from DB.

Oh, Entity Framework 6.0 btw.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should Time property (columns From and To) be a part of the same table (SomeEfModel) or could it be persisted in a separate table?

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy We want in the same table as the rest of the model.

Comment: So you want to implement a 1 to 0...1 relationship using table splitting (use the same table). I think it is not supported by EF.

Comment: @AndriyTolstoy Thanks for your answer, even though I don't like the outcome of it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You should define your class with nullable properties and then map a dto in the business layer to work with the non nullable values.

```
public partial class SomeEfModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimePeriod Time { get; set; }
}
public class DateTimePeriod
{
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}
```

And after this you should create a separate class that will map some default values for the DateTimePeriod:

```
public class DateTimePeriodDto
{
    public DateTime From {get; set; }
    public DateTime To {get; set; }

    public DateTimePeriodDto(DateTimePeriod dataObject)
    {
        From = dataObject.From ?? //put a default value
        To = dataObject.To ?? //put a default value
    }
}
```

And you should have at the end something like this:

```
public partial class SomeEfModelDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimePeriodDto Time { get; set; }
    public SomeEfModelDto(SomeEfModel model)
    {
        Id = model.Id;
        Time = new DateTimePeriodDto(model.DateTimePeriod);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this approach will be problematic to use due to how the project is setup though. :/

Comment: You're welcome, usually on all the projects we build, we have a separate Business Layer. It makes decoupling easy.